# passing value from VC1 to VC2

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I am now passing value from VC1 to VC2

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Menus/Day1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

            if let snapDict = snap.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>{

                let date = snapDict["mealPic"] as! String

                let OrderInfo = DataService.ds.REF_ORDER
                let USERUID = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
                let userinfo = OrderInfo.child(date).child(USERUID).child("data")

                self.valueToPass = date
            }
        })
    }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "ToVari") {
        var Vari = segue.destination as! Variation
        Vari.passedValue = valueToPass
    }
}
```

and my VC2 viewDidLoad:-

```
var passedValue : String! 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    MEALDATE.text = passedValue


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

It actually worked but the weird thing is the "passedValue" in VC2 didn't show at first (I select cell in VC1 to performSegue to VC2)

I had to go back to VC1 and then tap the cell to VC2 again to let "passedValue" showing what it supposed to be there.

anyone know why is this happening ?

Comment: I guess that your segue is directly from cell to next VC, and isn't your Firebase call async? I'd put the segue from VC1 to VC2 (not from cell in VC1), and once you set valueToPass, I'd perform the segue (potentially showing a spinner meanwhile).

Comment: First prepare for Segue method is gets called, after the didSelectRowAt method is called. Thats why at first time u get none value but again when u travel back & go u get the previous value that is stored in valueToPass variable

Comment: your didSelectRowAt of VC1 is call? or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be due to call to Firebase that is async (not 100% sure). Also You are calling segue from storyboard so I would suggest following:

- Remove segue from storyboard
- in your response from Firebase, add following: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToVari", sender: self)`

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the view controller life cycle. Simply put, when you perform a segue to another view controller, the app loads the view of the next view controller, then shows it. You need to keep this in mind when overriding `prepareForSegue`. At this point, the view of the next view controller has already been loaded, and in the case of a table, populated with what is essentially no data. To fix your problem, you simply need to tell the table to reload when the view appears. Just call `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear` on your new view controller. :)

Comment: Hi Jacob, I just have a plain UILabel in my VC2 to show the passedvalue. what do I call

Comment: Oh I apologies Ian, I was under the impression that your VC2 contained a table view. In the case of a plain label, just make sure you are calling `myLabel.text = passedValue` in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: damn I meant Jacob, stupid autocorrect  :( I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Firebase async call. You can follow @NickCatib solution or

```
func navigateToNextViewController(valueToPass: String) {
    let variation = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Variation") as! Variation
    variation.passedValue = valueToPass
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(variation, animated: true)
}
```

1. Call this function in Firebase async, pass value you want to it as

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in 
       self.navigateToNextViewController(date)
   })
2. Go to storyboard, select `viewController`, under '`identity inspector'->identity->storyboardId` -> give the `identifier`. This should be same as it is given in above function. (ex, give `identifier` name same as `viewController` name).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the Method of tableview to:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath 
 indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {    //put your code here 

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you perform segue after this line has been executed :

```
    self.valueToPass = date
```

only then you can call(Swift 3):

```
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVari", sender: Self)
```